# How to apply toastr when user get leveled up?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.4, toastr

This question is about when User get leveled up and toastr will pop up. This script is from my view blade template.

What I want to do is i want to put the toastr.js inside my script but I don't have idea how to implement.

** Profile.blade **

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
     $.toast({
        text: 'You level up!',
        heading: 'Congratulations',
        icon: 'info',
        position: 'top-right',
        bgColor: '#d4af37',
        textColor: 'black'
    });
   })
  </script>
```

** Controller **

```
          while($user->curr_exp >= $user->exp_needed){
             if($user->level == 10 || $user->level == 15 || $user->level == 20)
               {
                  $user->reward_token += 1;
               }
                  $user->curr_exp -= $user->exp_needed;   
                  $user->prev_exp = $user->exp_needed;
               if($user->level <= 19){
                   $user->exp_needed = $user->prev_exp * 1.4;
               }
               elseif($user->level >= 20 && $user->level <= 39){
                   $user->exp_needed = $user->prev_exp * 1.1;
               }
               elseif($user->level >= 40 && $user->level <= 59){
                   $user->exp_needed = $user->prev_exp * 1.05;
               }
               elseif($user->level >= 60 && $user->level <= 79){
                   $user->exp_needed = $user->prev_exp * 1.04;
               }
               elseif($user->level >= 80 && $user->level <= 99){
                   $user->exp_needed = $user->prev_exp * 1.03;
               }
               elseif($user->level == 100){
                   $user->exp_needed = $user->exp_needed * 0;
               }
                   $user->level += 1;
                   $user->save();
               }
```

Any ideas how to work this? I'm using laravel framework 5.4.36 version on this one. I'm just confused how to display a live notifications on the user's profile every time they leveled up.

Answer (score 1):

This link should help you.

https://laramust.com/post/toastr-notification-in-laravel-application

There are two methods on the page, scroll halfway down the page to the *'You can use by Installing toastr package'* part. I think that one will be most use to you.

Step 1: Install toastr package using composer.

```
$laravel_project> composer require yoeunes/toastr
```

Step 2: Include packages css and js file into layout.blade.php file or your view file where do you need to display toastr message.

```
@jquery - skip if already have.
@toastr_css - toastr css lib.
@toastr_js - toastr js lib.
@toastr_render - for render toastr notification
```

Step 3: Now add the service provider to config/app.php. In Laravel versions 5.5 and beyond, this step can be skipped if package auto-discovery is enabled.

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Yoeunes\Toastr\ToastrServiceProvider::class
    ...
];
```

Step 4: Call toastr method into controller file.

```
toastr()->info('User has been created!')
//set message with title
toastr()->success('Have fun storming the castle!', 'Miracle Max Says')
```

Good luck!!

Comment: It's says "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages." Because I'm using laravel framework version is 5.4.36

Comment: Are you getting that error on step 1? If so, try this link: https://packagist.org/packages/brian2694/laravel-toastr Try the instructions under the *Laravel <= 5.4* header